# Sonar analysis hangs on Execute decorators

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs, cobertura

I am using Sonar with Ant, importing Cobertura and unit test results and running code quality analysis with setting "Sonar + FindBugs". I have previously been able to analyse my (large) project with Sonar. I don't know, maybe I have done some changes but now the analysis does not finish anymore. Sonar has successfully imported Cobertura reports, then it tries to execute decorators but it just hangs (for hours):

p.PhasesTimeProfiler - Execute decorators...

I have tested this both on Windows7 and RHEL 6 machines. I have increased ANT java heap to 2048M. With smaller setting I usually at some point get a java heap exceeded -exception. The process is currently running, and the process is using 2266M of memory.

Any ideas? :)

The final lines before Sonar hangs are below (debug mode):

```
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.348 DEBUG raphMetricAggregator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.350 DEBUG emDashBoardDecorator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.505 DEBUG raphMetricAggregator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.505 DEBUG emDashBoardDecorator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.986 DEBUG raphMetricAggregator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.986 DEBUG emDashBoardDecorator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.994 DEBUG raphMetricAggregator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:24.995 DEBUG emDashBoardDecorator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:25.206 DEBUG raphMetricAggregator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:25.206 DEBUG emDashBoardDecorator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:25.214 DEBUG raphMetricAggregator - Checking for resource type: CLA
[sonar:sonar] 10:25:25.214 DEBUG emDashBoardDecorator - Checking for resource type: CLA
```

With SQL set to verbose in Sonar Ant target, the final SQL statement where it hangs on is this:

```
[sonar:sonar] 10:00:31.855 DEBUG    org.hibernate.SQL - select snapshot0_.id as
id7_, snapshot0_.build_date as build2_7_, snapshot0_.created_at as created3_7_,
snapshot0_.depth as depth7_, snapshot0_.islast as islast7_, snapshot0_.parent_sn
apshot_id as parent6_7_, snapshot0_.path as path7_, snapshot0_.period1_date as p
eriod8_7_, snapshot0_.period1_mode as period9_7_, snapshot0_.period1_param as pe
riod10_7_, snapshot0_.period2_date as period11_7_, snapshot0_.period2_mode as pe
riod12_7_, snapshot0_.period2_param as period13_7_, snapshot0_.period3_date as p
eriod14_7_, snapshot0_.period3_mode as period15_7_, snapshot0_.period3_param as
period16_7_, snapshot0_.period4_date as period17_7_, snapshot0_.period4_mode as
period18_7_, snapshot0_.period4_param as period19_7_, snapshot0_.period5_date as
 period20_7_, snapshot0_.period5_mode as period21_7_, snapshot0_.period5_param a
s period22_7_, snapshot0_.purge_status as purge23_7_, snapshot0_.qualifier as qu
alifier7_, snapshot0_.project_id as project25_7_, snapshot0_.root_snapshot_id as
 root26_7_, snapshot0_.root_project_id as root27_7_, snapshot0_.scope as scope7_
, snapshot0_.status as status7_, snapshot0_.version as version7_ from snapshots
snapshot0_ where snapshot0_.islast=? and snapshot0_.project_id=(select resourcem
o1_.id from projects resourcemo1_ where resourcemo1_.kee=?)
[sonar:sonar] 10:00:31.899 DEBUG    org.hibernate.SQL - select snapshotso0_.id a
s id13_, snapshotso0_.data as data13_, snapshotso0_.snapshot_id as snapshot3_13_
 from snapshot_sources snapshotso0_ where snapshotso0_.snapshot_id=?
```

In the second run I also got this:

```
[sonar:sonar] 11:16:40.149 DEBUG b.b.JdbcDriverHolder - To prevent a memory leak
, the JDBC Driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] has been forcibly deregistered
```

When I have not increase the java heap size and execute Sonar Ant target through Jenkins, I get the following:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2746)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:187)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:378)
    at     org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.ViolationTrackingDecorator.mapViolations(ViolationTrackingDecorator.java:131)
at org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.ViolationTrackingDecorator.decorate(ViolationTrackingDecorator.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:70)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:63)
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:63)
```

The above java heap space problem does not occur if I increase Ant to use 2048M, but then the Decorator hangs, as in the first error output.

Comment: Is your build running on the same machine as the MySQL server? We've noticed significant performance degradation when Sonar is run across the network, especially a WAN....

Comment: Both Sonar and MySQL are on the same machine

Comment: Could you run the analysis in Debug mode ("-X") in order to know which decorator is freezing?

Comment: I added the final debug lines to my original question post

Comment: added some more spam :) I added the final SQL statement that is outputted from Sonar when debug and sql verbose levels are set to max.

Comment: added SQL lines about jdbc being deregistered to prevent memory leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to report that I could not solve this problem without deleting the whole project from MySQL database. I noticed two changes I had made after it started hanging. 1) I seem to have changed the project key to something else, and 2) I had changed the quality profile from default to "Sonar + findbugs".

Sonar stopped working after 4 runs (i.e. 4 days), so I will see if this works from now on without changing my initial settings. The first run today morning went ok.